# Search query - Postcode, Company name or Location

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am a bit stuck with SQL queries.

User should be able to search Postcode, Company name or Location

I have the following tables:

**company table**

```
companyid |     name        | location
      1      Shop One           New York
      2      Shop Two           France
```

**postcode_areas table**

```
postcode | companyid
     BB1       1
     BB3       1
     BB1       2
```

So if user type in `BB1`, then it should show the result Shop One, and Shop Two.

If user type the name of company or location - it will just search from company table.

Comment: "If user type the name of company or location - it will just search from company table" - So you want to decide if what the user enters is a postcode before hand? In whcih case you should add another tag to your question. You suggest as though you want to do everything in SQL, but then say it will JUST search from the company table. You should use whatever language you are developing in and check the pattern of the search to determine if it is a valid zip/post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe:

```
select distinct c.*
from company c
join postcode_areas p on p.company_id = c.company_id
where c.name like <input>
or c.location like <input>
or p.postcode like <input>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a join of both tables and do an OR-search on all fields:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.* FROM company c JOIN postcode_areas p USING (companyid)
WHERE c.name = "$QUERY" OR c.location = "$QUERY" OR p.postcode = "$QUERY";
```

You might use `LIKE "%$QUERY%"` to get results for partial queries.